# Using OpenSessionInViewInterceptor in Java Config not WebXML

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have seen a lot of examples of adding `OpenSessionInViewFilter` and `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor`, and it seems like the Interceptor is the way I need to go.  My application is setup using Java Configuration and not web.xml style configs.

In my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` I am setting up the Interceptor as such:

```
@Bean
public OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor(){
    OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
    openSessionInViewInterceptor.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return openSessionInViewInterceptor;
}
```

This seems to be fine, but the problem is how do I get this hooked into my Spring configuration?

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(openSessionInViewInterceptor());
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
}
```

After trying this it compiles and runs just fine, but I still run into `could not initialize proxy - no Session` errors on the front end.  Is it actually hooking up like I want through this function, or is there another (more correct) way to add this interceptor?

Has anyone configured this kind of `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` inside Java Spring config?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the stack trace. You're looking at very outdated documentation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Got it compiling and all, still getting session `could not initialize proxy - no Session` errors.  Going to update the code blocks to the current try and update the question.